# PowerApps | Custom connector | Dynamic content missing

Tags: powerapps, swagger-2.0, power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector, power-apps-custom-connector

I have created a custom connector which I am adding in PowerApps and Power Automate. There is one action named "GetDetails" in custom connector to fetch details from an endpoint. Response from an endpoint is dynamic.
Sample response from end point:

```
{
    "data":  {
        //Some Dynamic Content 
    }
}
```

Swagger file response definition:

```
    get:
      responses:
        default:
          description: default
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              data: {type: object, description: data}      <---- Since dynamic properties in "data" at run time
```

Question:
Now when I use custom connector in Power Automate I get data property along with dynamic content. But when I use this custom connector in PowerApps I get empty data property. Dynamic content is missing.
[image: Output in PowerApps]

Answer (score 0):

When you say "...when I use this custom connector in PowerApps...", *how* are you using it? Likely, you're creating a Collection using something like:

```
ClearCollect(
    colDetails,
    MY_CUSTOM_CONN.GetDetails(someParameter)
)
```

You can try adding a `.` to the `ClearCollect` statement to see if the schema needs another "level". This is known as "dot notation". Just adding a "." can be a big help for exploring the different schema levels.

---

**EDIT 1**

Hm. If you've tested the response and validated using Power Automate (or Postman, etc.), the only things I can think of are:

1. Remove the `JSON()` function from your `ClearCollect()` statement.

- The Custom Connector should already be returning JSON, there shouldn't be any reason (I can think of) to use transform it on the PowerApps side.

2. If that doesn't work, "Rebuild" the Request in the Custom Connector.

- `Import from sample` under `Request`
- Enter the correct `Verb`, `Headers` and a sample JSON `Body`

[image]

Comment: I have added screenshot in question for more details. I am using "." notation but it gives an error since the object is empty.